# NRQL using the FACET count value as a filter

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I am hoping to FACET values together and then get a count of those values that have > 2 results.  I have this part.

```
SELECT count(*) as 'requestCount' FROM Transaction WHERE FACET SomeId
```

This returns

```
ID1 - 3
ID2 - 1
ID3 - 5
ID4 - 1
ID5 - 7
```

But I only want to know how many came back with a 'requestCount' > 2 .

So I only want to know that 3 items were above 2.  I don't even want to know the ID values only the roll up figure.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with [nested aggregation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/nrql-query-tutorials/nested-aggregation-make-ordered-computations-single-query/). There is an example there about average CPU that looks pretty similar to what you are looking for.

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT count(*) as 'requestCount' FROM Transaction WHERE FACET SomeId
) WHERE requestCount > 2
```